# Saving object as Text

Tags: javascript, json, postgresql, nestjs

I am trying to send a request which updates a field in database[pg].
I have a freelancer entity with a field that needs to be updated.

```
@Column('varchar', {
    array: true
})
work_days: string;
```

This is my postman request :

```json
{   
     "days": [1, 2] ,
        "time": {
            "to":8,
            "from": 9
        }
}
```

```
Also i have my DTO like: 

    @IsNotEmpty()
    days: number[];

    @IsNotEmpty()
    time: string;
```

What i want is to save this request body as text in my db.
But i get this error
`malformed array literal: "{"days":[1,2],"time":{"to":8,"from":9}}"`
I have tried using it as raw sql still having the same error. So i am sure there's something wrong with the syntax.

Comment: It's treating your data as a postgres array not a JSON string. Hard to say why with no more than you posted.

Comment: The problem is postman will take '[]' as array while postgres takes '{}' this as array.

Comment: How do i make it treat like a string? @JaredSmith

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you out: [U114: Malformed array literal](https://pganalyze.com/docs/log-insights/app-errors/U114)
As well as this: [PostGres Docs Arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT)

The string you want to pass needs to be passed in the right PostGres array syntax.

Comment: I've added a comment why this cant be a solution.